# How the option can be the?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

The following question is from a test:

> The epidemiologist was worried: despite _______ signs of danger, few countries or companies had taken the possibility of a pandemic seriously, and there was little interest in developing a vaccine.
>
> 1. erroneous
> 2. mounting
> 3. token
> 4. inconclusive
> 5. residual

The correct answer is given as **mounting**, but how can that be possible when there is a conjunction **"despite"** that refers to the opposite of the decisive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's divide your sentence into two parts, linked by **despite**.  We'll turn the first part into a sentence by adding a predicate:

> **A.** Mounting signs of danger *[ existed ]*.
>
> **B.** Few countries or companies had taken the possibility of a pandemic seriously, and there was little interest in developing a vaccine.

The overall structure of the sentence is **B, even though A is true**.  Because A is true, we'd expect B *not* to be true.  But B is true, **despite** A!

---

Let's try rephrasing **mounting signs of danger** as an independent and complete sentence:

> Over time, there was more and more evidence that it was dangerous.

Based on this sentence, we'd expect the following reactions:

1. Countries and companies should take the possibility of a pandemic seriously.
2. There should be interest in developing a vaccine.

But we don't get either of those reactions.  We get the opposite.  So, we say that we got the opposite **despite** the mounting signs of danger.